# Bootstrap: How to remove click event from button

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

[**Twitter Bootstrap**](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals) has the ability to call modals "via data attributes", which is nice, but I am not sure how to turn them off or replace the button's event.

Example of setting up via attributes:

```
<button id="launch-btn" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
   Launch modal
</button>
```

I've tried:

```
$('#launch-btn').off('click');
$('#launch-btn').unbind('click');
$('#launch-btn').on('click', function(e){e.preventDefault();});
```

But all seem to still open the modal.  I want to prevent the default modal from opening and replace it with another action if a condition is met.  I know I can use the modal's `show` event to prevent displaying, but I don't want to do that here, I want to control the behavior from the button.

I also realize it might be easier to handle the creation of the modal on-the-fly instead using JS instead of letting bootstrap handle it via the data attributes, but I'm now a curious george and am trying to discover what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: looking at bootstrap-modal.js.. this is how they bind their click event `$(document).on('click.modal.data-api', '[data-toggle="modal"]'`

Comment: @wirey: yes - I did the same thing.  I was surprised at how easy it was to follow the plugin.  I was in the middle of my answer as using `off` for that does work.  I'm testing how to do it using the button's ID.

Comment: I'm wondering if maybe [event.stopImmediatePropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/) would work for what you need since the event handlers are bound to the document. **Maybe Not**  It seems delegated events can't stop propagation

Comment: @wirey: I think we're doing the same research - I came to same conclusion.  I haven't yet tried using Tony's suggestion, through attribute handling (it sounds like it'd work in theory); otherwise, I'm going to give up and re-evaluate the current document structure.  If I have to use more self-written JavaScript than I intended, I might as well do it right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works: `$(document).off('click.modal.data-api', '[data-toggle="modal"]');`

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the modal's show option to false:

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals

You can just append another data attribute:

```
<button id="launch-btn" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-show="false" data-target="#myModal">
   Launch modal
</button>
```

Comment: So I'd like the default condition to exist (it to show when the button is clicked) unless the page contains some bit of data, in which case I'd like to turn it off.  Looking at the jQuery API, it seems like `off` only works for how `on` registered the handler, which in this case was for everything for modal

Comment: That could be applied through jQuery. $('#launch-btn').attr('data-show','false'); ... that way you can make the action or lack of action situation-dependent.

Comment: that is exactly what I was looking for.  I'm curious how changing the attribute triggers a JavaScript event.  I understand the initial JS uses it, but I didn't realize this is updated or used after the page is loaded.  Perhaps this is something specific to HTML5, or I am missing the magic in bootstrap-modal.js; regardless, update your answer and I will upvote/select it.

Comment: Actually doesn't seem to be doing it on the fly when testing: `$('#launch-btn').click(function(){$(this).attr('data-show',toggle()+'')})` where `toggle` is a function that toggles and returns a true/false global value.  My assumption is that I should be able to go back-and-forth between off and on events.

Comment: true/false would be a string, and if its a function creating the true/false its likely just producing a 0/1, which wouldn't have the same result. try having your function create a string true/false.

Comment: It is producing 'true' and 'false'.  I outputted to console for testing and also looked at the element attribute update through Firebug element inspector.  It just didn't seem to work.  I'm in the process of writing an extension to the bootsrap-modal.js.  I have a page that has many different modals, and I need a better way of creating them through JS, if I'm going to do so.  I don't consider modals content, but instead interface interactions/workflow, so I think they should be outside of the document's HTML on initial load.